# Heroku/Rails route example.com to mydomain.example/example

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, dns, routes

My rails app is a way for users to create their own basic website.  So each of them will have a root folder that is `example.com/user/1`.  They will have other pages like `example.com/user/1/about` etc.  How do I configure Rails and Heroku so that something like `www.user1.example` points to `example.com/user/1`, and something like `www.user1.example/about` directs to `example.com/user/1/about`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I did in my app was first have the list of user domains in the database.  Then create an advanced constraint 
http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

In this case, my constraint class looks like this:

```
class UserDomainConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    UserDomain.all.map(&:domain_name).include? request.domain
  end
end
```

And then use that constraint in the route

```
root to: 'user_domains#index', :constraints: UserDomainConstraint
```

My action then takes a look at request.domain and acts accordingly.

Comment: Does this: UserDomain.all.map(&:domain_name).include?  return the user ID?  In other words, how does user_domains#index know what the user is? Second, is this any better/different than having them simply CNAME directly to mydomain.com/users/1?  Especially for SSL.

Comment: No, the include? statement just does a lookup for the domain.  In order to serve up the pages, you'd probably need another route like
`match :page` to: 'user_pages#show'.